# Why Am I Getting Different Time Values

Tags: c++, windows-7-x64, cpu-time

I've tried this code in C++ on Win7x64 platform with MSVC++, and I got CPU frequency about 2900000 ticks per second.

When I run this program, my stopwatch returns about 10,000,000 tick, which means it take about 4 seconds to process my program, but my program results are ready for me in 1 second (or less) O_o.

Could you please tell me what is wrong in my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <string.h>



using namespace std;

#define CV_TO_NANO 1000000000
#define CV_TO_MICRO 1000000
#define CV_TO_MILLI 1000

 unsigned __int64 inline GetRDTSC()
{
   __asm
   {
      ; Flush the pipeline
      XOR eax, eax
      CPUID
      ; Get RDTSC counter in edx:eax
      RDTSC
   }
}

unsigned __int64 RunTest(TCHAR *AppName, TCHAR *CmdLine);

 void main()
 {  
     unsigned __int64 start = 0;
     unsigned __int64 stop = 0;
     unsigned __int64 freq = 0;
     float rps;
     ofstream dataFile;


     // get processor freq
     QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER *)&freq);
     cout <<"freq (count per second): "<< freq << endl;
     // round per second
     rps = 1.0/(freq);
     cout <<"rps (1/rps): "<< rps << endl;
     dataFile.open ("d:/dataC.txt",ios::out );
     for(int i = 0;i<200;i++)
     {
        SetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(),0x0001);
        SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(),0x0001);
        cout << RunTest(L"D:\\Child\\Child.exe", NULL);
     }
    getchar();
    return;
 }

unsigned __int64 RunTest(TCHAR *AppName, TCHAR *CmdLine)
{
    unsigned __int64 start = 0;
    unsigned __int64 stop = 0;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
    memset(&processInformation, 0, sizeof(processInformation));
    memset(&startupInfo, 0, sizeof(startupInfo));
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);

    BOOL result;
    start = GetRDTSC();
    result = ::CreateProcess(AppName, CmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);
    stop = GetRDTSC();
    getchar();
    if (result == 0)
    {
        wprintf(L"ERROR: CreateProcess failed!");
    }
    else
    {
        WaitForSingleObject( processInformation.hProcess, 0 );
        CloseHandle( processInformation.hProcess );
        CloseHandle( processInformation.hThread );
    }
    return stop - start;
}
```

Comment: You can't be compiling x64.  `asm` isn't supported on x64.

Comment: you should be using the `__rdtsc()` intrinsic for windows x64

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. what is the different between QueryPerformanceCounter and __rdtsc()

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a misconception here that `QueryPerformanceFrequency` is telling you something about the speed of your processor - it isn't.  [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) retrieves the frequency of the high-resolution performance counter, which is not guaranteed to have any predictable relationship to your CPU clock speed.  This value needs to be used in conjunction with [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to get quality timing values, not with assembly that directly queries the RDTSC.

Comment: when I use QueryPerformanceCounter(), sometime, It return 0. Is that an error result?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use the high-frequency timer to time a block of code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li = {};
    __int64 freq, start, stop;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li);
    freq = li.QuadPart;

    cout << "Counter Frequency: " << freq << "\n";

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    start = li.QuadPart;

    for( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
    {
        int n = i * rand();
    } 

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    stop = li.QuadPart;

    double elapsed_seconds = static_cast<double>(stop-start) / static_cast<double>(freq);

    cout << "Elapsed Time: " << elapsed_seconds << " seconds\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. but why 'freq' = 2.9m. I use 3.06GHz CPU